# How to get an unselected value from a gridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need to be able to delete a record from a GridView, but in order to do so, i need to to a method on the .cs file. The thing is that i have other tables that have the ID of a train associated with it, so i need to display an error message if the delete command fails. My problem is that, i can only delete a record when that record is selected.
(GridView2.**SelectedDataKey**). I want to be able to delete it when it's not selected.

Something like GriView2.Datakey .....

aspx page:

```
<LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
CommandName="" Text="DELETE" OnClick ="del" >
```

.cs code:

```
protected void del(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string DeleteSql = "DELETE FROM [Trains] WHERE [ID_Train] = @ID_Train";

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(DeleteSql, Connection);
    String key = GridView2.SelectedDataKey["ID_Train"].ToString();

        try
        {

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Train", key);

            cn.Open();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();

            Response.Redirect("Trains.aspx");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Label5.Text = "Error";
            Label5.Visible = true;
        }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the associated record across all other GridViews when a selected record in one GridView is deleted?

Comment: No, what i want is that if the record is associated with other tables, then it shows an error message. If not, it deletes the record. The thing is that i had the delete command on the aspx page, but when i deleted a record i had the error Key constraint violation page. so i converted the delete, insert and select to template fields so i could add "Onclick" to add a method and a try and exeption

Comment: i hope i'm making myself clear. My problem is super simple. But i don't know how to do it. xD If i delete, and theres no violation, then it deletes the record from the gridview and table, if theres a violation then it show an error message. The thing is that i want to be able to delete without the record to be selected on the gridview.

Comment: ok that makes more sense, so you have database tables that have foreign key relationships that are forcing the delete to fail.  I get that.  What do you mean you want to delete without the record being selected?  you can easily delete records programatically as long as you can obtain the delete criteria, so if you have nothing selected where is the delete criteria coming from?

Comment: hum.. for instance, on the aspx page, i had showdeletebutton=true Delete command = "Delete query" and  the <DeleteParameters> <asp:Parameter Name="ID_Train" Type="String" />, so when the gridview was loaded i didnt need to select on the gridview the record to delete it. But if convert to a templetefield in order to add the Onclick command in order to delete a record i need to declare the variable @ID_Train, and therefore use the .SelectedDataKey to do it

Comment: ah, ok.  So when you edit columns you modified the CommandButton to enable delete and disable select, yes?

Comment: sorry i didn't see your replay until now. what i do is when i edit columns the Select and insert still are InsertCommand = "Insert" and SelectCommand = "Select"(and the insert and select queries are on the aspx page). The delete however is DeleteCommand = "" Onclik ="del" (del being the method from the .cs page)

Comment: Add the delete command to the datasource and see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a template construct similar to this:

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

AND you have a Delete command in your SqlDataSource, you can process the delete command and access the datakeys in the RowCommand Event like this (Note I converted this from VB so the C# might be off, but you get the idea):

```
private void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
{
    if( e.CommandName == "Delete" ) {
        string TrainID  = GridView1.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Values("ID_Train");
        integer rc = 0;
        GridView1.DeleteParameters.Clear();
        GridView1.DeleteParameters.Add("Train_ID", TrainId);   // Adjust as necessary

        try{
            rc = GridView1.Delete();
            if( rc == 1) {
               // Deleted
            } else {
               // Not Deleted
            }
        }
        catch() {
            Label5.Text = "Error";
            Label5.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. I got stuck at college today, just had the opportunity to check your message, and i have some problems with some commands that you have there. I'm using visual studio 2010 and it doesnt recognize the .DeleteParameters and the .Delete(). Also where you have Handles GridView1.RowCommand. That's just a comment right ?? because that doesn't recognize either. Hope you can help me.

Comment: I'll do what I can.  First you have to use the designer and add the Delete SQL to it like you've done for the Select and Insert (you mentioned they are there in the aspx so I'm assuming you know how to add the Delete option).  then the Delete and DeleteParameters should become available from RowCommand once you refresh the GridView datasource (without updating the fields)

Comment: And about that Handles command - no, it's not a comment - its VB syntax that I forgot to translate to C#.  It shouldn't matter tho just go into your code behind and select the appropriate gridview from the object drop down list and then select the RowCommand event and it should drop the C# handler into the page for you

Comment: Done it. Thanks so much! One last question. I have some linkbuttons on other pages. The thing is that the linkButton is a blue different from the gridview auto Format (mine is professional). Is there any way to add that css to the linkbutton? For example if i use commandfield like showselectbutton = true, it stays on the same format as the gridview itself. Thanks for all the help again!

Comment: yes - see the LinkButton CssClass property.  you can do something like this `<asp:LinkButton CssClass="Blue Bold"></asp:LinkButton>` where .Blue and .Bold exist in some included stylesheet

Comment: Or you can programmatically add inline styles in say the RowDataBound event like this: `LinkButton lb = e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton1"); if(lb != null){ lb.Style.Add("background-color","blue");}`

Comment: Thanks once again. Take care